# "Don't catch generic Exceptions!" But how to unravel them?

Tags: java, exception, error-handling, static-analysis

Most of the static code analysis tools suggest not to catch generic (in particular unchecked) exceptions like RuntimeExceptions and Errors.

Unless this Exception barrier might be reasonable at a top level, generally it isn't at a lower level.
Unfortunately this can be very difficult to achive when rewriting/fixing already existing code, because the underlying possibilities of possible Errors and RuntimeExceptions can be exorbitant.
Moreover, it is mostly a really time consuming and complex task to dig into the lower code levels to gain some ideas of Exceptions reasonable enough to catch instead of the generic catch.

Do you know any tools or best practices to unravel such generic (unchecked) exceptions into more specific ones?

say we have something like that:

```
try
{
    somethingReallyComplex();
}
catch (RuntimeException | Error ex)
{
    Logger.error(this, ex.getClass().getName() + " while doing something really complex", ex)
}
```

The try block can contain a really complex matter of code with a variety of different RuntimeExceptions and Errors which **make sense** to catch.
But how can I analyse this code most effectively to unravel the RuntimeException into NullPointerException, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException... whatever might be reasonable?

Are there any tools that can analyze such code and give suggestions about most common RuntimeExceptions in there and the like?

How do you start to solve this problem?

Where is the subjective or objective "threshold" to say: 
"No, I just leave it as RuntimeException and add a suppress annotation?"

Comment: Is this at the top of whatever the sensible stack is, e.g. as a top level handler within a server? If so, catching plain `Exception` (to include all `RuntimeException` values but not `Error`) makes sense, to prevent a bug from bringing down a whole server. If it's *not* at the top level, it really shouldn't be catching these exceptions. Oh, and SQLException *isn't* a RuntimeException.

Comment: Yes it is a server application and mostly those catches work as exception barriers, but often this is implemented not at the top level, but on a deeper code level. Therefore I search a good method to unravel those generics into more specific exceptions.

Comment: It is wrong to have any more than a single exception barrier. You should simply **delete** those handlers to let the exceptioms propagate upwards. There is really no handling of an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`. You just need to log the full stacktrace, including the causes.

Comment: @ Marko: Yes, but if you are on a code with thousands of thousands of code lines and objects, this might be rather challenging to rework.

Answer (score 7):

The most important thing about catching general Exceptions is *where* you catch them, not *whether*. If you do it at a central place, a so-called *exception barrier*, which is high up in the call stack, then that is exactly what you should be doing. It would be a bad practice if you did it in the middle of your code, at some more or less arbitrary point.

Comment: I agree, but PMD (or any code analysis tool with this "do not catch generic exception" rule) doesn't care about where did you put the generic catch and still marks that code as an issue :(

Comment: That's what rule suppressions are for.

Answer (score 2):

The burden of proof should not be on you, but on the tool that wants you to change your code. Any reasonable static analysis tool will give the rationale behind a particular warning, enabling you to asses the impact of ignoring that warning in your particular circumstances. (Most warnings exist because the code they flag is *often* problematic, not because it *always* is.)

There are certainly situations where catching Exception is the right thing to do because your recovery logic is so general it doesn't need to distinguish among exceptions, for instance if you implement something like: "If something goes wrong, retry twice. If it still didn't work, log the exception, inform the user, and move on". It really depends on what your exception handler does.

Comment: That's correct in my eyes, but unfortunately I am not in the state of setting up a new architecture, but to fix up already existing code by reviewing the static analysis results.
And there are several cases in which the original developer just catches RuntimeException, because of his... lazyness or whatever.
Often enough this is combined in the restriction of not changing the API declarations. So I even cannot modify the unchecked exceptions into checked ones where it would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Although it isn't recommended I usually catch the generic exceptions, after all the only thing I'm going to do with it is write to the log and move on.

If you had to preform different cleanup tasks based on what blew up then it might be useful to have 6 or whatever catch blocks after the try.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion each part of the code should catch the exception it knows how to handle, and all the checked exception it throws should have a meaning related to this code. A basic mechanism is to wrap all exception handled into the type of checked exception this method throws. The exceptions to this rule  (huhu) are RuntimeExceptions and mostly Errors which you should not try to catch (see [Error javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html)).

So for me each of the methods in your try{} block should throw checked exceptions with a semantic related to the method. And recursively you do the same on all these methods, but I cant see any tool smart enough to do that for you.

Comment: Yes, but this can lead even deeper into the code with massive code changes. And the most problematic restriction: I cannot change API declarations. So throwing checked exceptions is often not an option, if the API-element already exists.

Comment: The only business semantics of 99% real-world exceptions is "An error occurred processing the request. Sorry" and the only point of a domain-specific exception is its business semantics. In other words, it is 99% **useless** and nothing but a burden.

Comment: Viewing this only from a business side, this is correct. However, the product is mainly based on customization. Therefore a reliable and comprehensible exception source is more than only good manner. But to maintain a good source quality is difficult, if 200 developers are working on the same product. That's why it is a good idea to split up generic exceptions intro several Sub-exceptions.

Comment: Indeed, often the exception will just be reported to the user as you said Marko, but in some cases:
- you build an API, so the user is a developper and has to take decisions in turn depending on the checked exception
- your own code need to clean stuffs before handing back control to the user depending on the type of the exception its component threw; like rollback transactions.
But I agree its quite a burden to maintain but in small teams of experienced people its an affordable quality of code.